# How to type a multi-column message in a telegram bot in google script

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, telegram, telegram-bot

so I use this [code](https://gist.github.com/unnikked/828e45e52e217adc09478321225ec3de) to build my bot and it works fine
but when I type a longe message (use enter to make a new newline) it refuses to save

so as you can see in [the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cx2A.png) When it is in one column  it works fine
but when I press enter to make a "space" between them like a normal chat it all miss up!

this works fine :

```
 bus.on(/\/first_semester/, function () {
                    this.replyToSender("/Business_language");
                    this.replyToSender("/Political_science");
                    this.replyToSender("/Management");
              });
```

while this give error :

```
bus.on(/\/Accounting/, function () {
                          this.replyToSender('bla lba
bal bla ')
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can not use newlines (enter) in normal strings

You would need to use backticks to accept spaces - `` ` ``

In JavaScript / Apps Script:

```js
// THESE ARE OK
var string1 = 'Hello';
var string2 = "Hello";
var string3 = `Hello`;

// THESE GIVE ERRORS
var string4 = 'Hello
Hello';
var string5 = "Hello
Hello";

// THIS IS OK
var string6 = `Hello
Hello`;
```

#### Reference

- [Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)